# Need to show the progress bar while copying the file in Perl

Tags: perl, progress-bar, cp

I am copying the file from source location to destination location and file size is too big. I want to see the progress bar in terminal window when file is getting copied. Here is the sample snippet of the Perl code:

```
$src_dir = "/home/user/source/";
$dest = "/home/user/destination/";

$file = $src_dir."test_file.csv";

`cp $file $dest`;

print "Copy Done\n";
```

File is getting copied here after certain seconds. But need to display the progress bar in terminal window. How we can achieve this?

Comment: You can copy the file by writing it line by line from within perl (not using `cp`) then you could use for example [Term::ProgressBar](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ProgressBar). But I guess you will need to know (calculate) the number of lines in the file first, so it might not be possible without reading the file twice

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can implement a progress bar using [Term::ProgressBar](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ProgressBar). It uses [sysread](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysread.html) and [syswrite](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/syswrite.html) to write a fixed block size at a time:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Term::ProgressBar;
use constant BUFSIZE => 8196;

my $fn = 'file.txt';
my $save_fn = 'file2.txt';
my $size = -s $fn;
my $progress = Term::ProgressBar->new ({count => $size, remove => 1});


open ( my $read_fh, '<:raw', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
open ( my $write_fh, '>:raw', $save_fn ) or die "Could not open file '$save_fn': $!";

my $buf = "";

my $total_written = 0;
my $next_update = 0;
while (1) {
    my $bytes_read = sysread $read_fh, $buf, BUFSIZE;
    die "Read error: $!" if !defined $bytes_read;
    last if $bytes_read == 0;
    my $offset = 0;
    my $num_bytes = $bytes_read;
    while (1) {
        my $bytes_written = syswrite $write_fh, $buf, $num_bytes, $offset;
        die "Write error: $!" if !defined $bytes_written;
        die "Unexpected" if $bytes_written > $num_bytes;
        last if $bytes_written == $num_bytes;
        $num_bytes -= $bytes_written;
        $offset += $bytes_written;
    }
    $total_written += $bytes_read;
    if ( $total_written > $next_update ) {
        $next_update = $progress->update($total_written);
    }
}
$progress->update($size);
close $read_fh;
close $write_fh;
```

Comment: Thanks @hakon. But this is something like I am doing a operation inside a file right? I dont want to go inside file, all I want is show the progress bar till the script reaches at the end.

Comment: In order to copy the file you need to go inside it. I am not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You've asked a surprisingly complex question.  You want to run an external command (`cp`) while at the same time having the Perl program continue executing (producing progress information). In other words, they are both executing at the same time.

The classic way to do this is to execute the external command in a separate process and output updates while waiting for that process to complete.

The first part is typically done by `fork`ing the process.  It's easy to get this wrong, so I suggest using [Proc::Fork](https://metacpan.org/pod/Proc::Fork).

The second part needs a bit of finesse, as you need to sit around and wait for the process to end, but need to output something every now and then, but don't want to busy-wait and burn CPU cyles.  The safest way to do this is to sleep in-between outputs.  For that I recommend [Time::HiRes](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::HiRes) (which is part of the standard Perl distribution).

And, here's some code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use English; # for more mnemonic special variable names

use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";
use Proc::Fork;
use Time::HiRes qw( usleep );

run_fork {
    child {
        exec q[sleep 3];
    }
    parent {
        my $child_pid = shift;

        my $pid;
        my $loop;
        STDOUT->autoflush;
        while ( 0 == ($pid = waitpid $child_pid, WNOHANG ) ){
            print '.';
            ++$loop;
            usleep(5000);
        }
        print "\n" if $loop;

        # for more complete handlng of $CHILD_ERROR, see the
        # documentation for the perl system function

        die( "error in child process\n" ) if $CHILD_ERROR;

    }
};
```

If you want fancy progress bars, take a look at [Term::ProgressBar](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ProgressBar)